# nodeJS: forEach loop is not a function, error

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach

I'm using `array.forEach()` function and I get an error that

> parsedBody.forEach is not a function.

The `parseBody` produces a value and I've used `forEach` in other methods and the function works fine. So why is `forEach` not working in this case?

Edit: parseBody is an object. How do I turn it into an array?

---

(server.js):

```
console.log('- before request.post');

            request.post({
                url: `${dc_link}/audit`, //includes dc_IP, dc_port and /audit
                headers: 
                    {     
                    "jwt": jwt.sign(token, jwtSecret)
                }
            }, function(error,response,body){  //*
                    console.log('path 0');
                    console.log('error:', error);
                    let parseBody = JSON.parse(body);
                    console.log('parseBody.additionalData', parseBody.additionalData);

                parseBody.forEach(function(element){   //**HERE
                    console.log('path 3');

                });
                }
```

---

(console.log):

```
[stdout] - before request.post
[stdout] start respondWithJSON
[stderr] /app/server.js:435
[stderr]                parseBody.forEach(function(element, index, array){ //*
[stderr]                          ^
[stderr] TypeError: parseBody.forEach is not a function
[stderr]     at Request._callback (/app/server.js:435:15)
[stderr]     at Request.self.callback (/app/node_modules/request/request.js:188:22)
[stderr]     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
[stderr]     at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
[stderr]     at Request.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/request/request.js:1171:10)
[stderr]     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
[stderr]     at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
[stderr]     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/request/request.js:1091:12)
[stderr]     at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:286:16)
[stderr]     at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
[stdout] path 0
[stdout] error: null
[stdout] parseBody.additionalData iAAGtYgBAGkCBFoW4F4DARkDAQkDAQUDAQ
```

Comment: i guess parsebody is not an array

Comment: Check if `parsedBody` is an Array (`parseBody instanceof Array` or something like that)

Comment: @Andreas he's trying to decode `parseBody`, not `parseBody.additionalData`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

parseBody appears to be an object since you're accessing it with dot notation. You need an array to use the forEach method. Turn parseBody into an array, and the problem is solved.

To turn it into an array, here is one possible solution:

```
  var arr = Object.keys(parseBody).map(function(key){ return parseBody[key]; });
```

Comment: How do I turn the parseBody object into an array. I tried using parseBody.toArray(array_result) => { array_result.forEach( (element) => {console.log('path 3'); }); But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think parseBody is an object and not an array thus you cant use foreach, perhaps try this:

```
for(var key in parseBody){
 console.log("result: " + parseBody[key]);
}
```